# Why does an IO Thread in dotnet dramatically slow down when there are other Tasks running?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-core, io

On my machine, reading a ~1.3GB file takes about ~13 seconds using the following code:

```
 static void ReadFileToBuffer()
        {
            var inputBuffer = new byte[1_300_000_000];
            var ioStopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            ioStopwatch.Start();

            int idx = 0;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (sr.Peek() > -1)
                {
                    //Could make this faster using ReadBlock
                    var data = sr.Read();
                    inputBuffer[idx] = (byte)data;
                    idx++;
                }
            }
            ioStopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Write bytes To Buffer Read finished: {ioStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

        }
```

Running this code in a separate thread, and then waiting for it to join also takes ~13 seconds

```
public static void Main()
{
    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
    {
        ReadFileToBuffer();
    });
    t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
    t.Start();
    t.Join();
}
```

However, as soon as I start doing a bunch of non-allocating work using other threads, the IO thread dramatically slows down. This program takes 30 seconds to run over the same input file:

```
 public static void Main()
        {
            var mainStopwatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            mainStopwatch.Start();

            Thread t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                ReadFileToBuffer();
            });
            t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            t.Start();


            Task[] taskArray = new Task[System.Environment.ProcessorCount-4];

            var dummy_arr = new string[10000].Select((e, i) => i).ToArray();
            long idx = 0;
            bool run = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
            {
                taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {

                    while (run)
                    {
                        //Do some dummy CPU bound work that doesn't allocate
                        var myIdx= System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref idx);
                        dummy_arr[myIdx % 10000] = dummy_arr[myIdx % 10000].GetHashCode();
                    }
                });
            }
            t.Join();
            run = false;
            mainStopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"Full Program {mainStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds} - dummy work ran {idx} times");
        }
```

Does anyone know why this is the case, and what can be done about it?

I am especially interested in the "why". Is the thread scheduler just not good at leaving IO threads alone?

- DotNet Core 3.1
- Windows 10 Version    10.0.19042 Build 19042
- Installed Physical Memory (RAM)   16.0 GB
- Processor AMD Ryzen 5 1600X Six-Core Processor, 3600 Mhz, 6 Core(s), 12 Logical Processor(s)
- NVMe Samsung SSD 960 SCSI

Comment: Without a lot more information, it's impossible to say. That said, **why are you surprised that when you put a large number of threads into busy loops, other threads suffer?** The only thing even marginally defensible in the code above is you set the number of busy threads to the processor count minus 4. ...

Comment: ... But there's no evidence you're taking into account the question of hyperthreading, which makes a CPU look like it has twice as many _useful cores_ as it really does. You would have to cut the active thread count down to no more than five, and possibly even fewer, for there to be a CPU core left over to handle your I/O.

Comment: With 5 busy threads, the IO thread is 50% slower (~18s) than with no busy threads (~13s). Your perception is that this is expected behavior? Meaning that there is no efficient way to use other threads while IO is taking place? As a point of context - non IO threads are not not slowed down this dramatically when you spin up other, unrelated threads.

Comment: _"non IO threads are not not slowed"_ -- Non-I/O threads aren't yielding. Your I/O thread is the worst-case scenario. It reads one byte at a time, which is the slowest way to empty the underlying buffer(s), then it yields. A CPU-bound thread won't yield until it has to (IIRC thread quantum is 50 ms, far longer than the I/O thread is likely to use at a time). So, yes...I don't see anything untoward about your example. You've hobbled the I/O thread, then sent a bunch of CPU-bound threads to take it to the ground. It's no surprise it loses.

Comment: Nit: your 5-thread test doesn't produce a result of _"50% slower"_. It produces a result of "50%" _longer_ (and it's really only 40%). The actual I/O rate is about 70%, which is only _30%_ **slower**.

Comment: >It reads one byte at a time ... then it yields.  - where is the IO thread yielding? Does  StreamReader.Read() yield behind the scenes? Or does a while loop have an invisible yield?

Comment: _"where is the IO thread yielding?"_ -- every time the underlying buffers run out of data, the thread has no choice but to yield. According to [publicly available source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,6875bce072fdba23) default buffer in `StreamReader` is 1K, with a 4K buffer for the underlying `FileStream` object. The OS _may_ cache data, so not all reads to replenish those buffers will necessarily require yielding, but with 1.3GB, you're definitely going to be yielding numerous times during the I/O. This is typical for I/O, and is one of ...

Comment: ... the main reasons we use async APIs to deal with it, because otherwise you'd be tying up a thread for unnecessarily long periods of time waiting for new data to arrive from whatever device you're reading from, something that's particularly important where thread pool threads are involved, but should be of concern to any programmer in any case.

Comment: As far as "where is the yield" goes, at the lowest level there's a call to the OS to retrieve data from the file. That call internally uses a wait, and that wait is what signals to the OS thread scheduler that the thread no longer needs the CPU and is yielding.